# Yii2 How can i use activequery for unique validators in my model

Tags: validation, yii2, unique

How can i use activequery for unique validators in my model

```
  ['amenityName', 'unique', 'targetClass' => Amenity::className(), 'message' => 'This amenity has already been taken.',
                 'when' => function ($model, $attribute) {
                   return $model->{$attribute} !== $model->getOldAttribute($attribute);
               },],
```

in activequery

```
public function active()
{  
        return $this->andWhere(['amenityStatus' => '1']);
} 

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return Amenity[]|array
     */
    public function all($db = null)
    {
        return parent::all($db);
    }
```

i want to get unique value of amenityname whose data is active. now im it checking from all data which is not active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the unique validator directly .. eg in Amenity  Model:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
               // a1 needs to be unique in the column represented by the "a1" attribute
              ['amenityName', 'unique'],
              ....
```

and you can get more infor about unique validator features here  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique
and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html

Comment: Thank u very much it helps a lot.